# Measuring an electrical signal without tapping wires

Tags: voltage, capacitance

I came across a product which taps into a twisted pair differential signal without making physical contact with the conductors. Instead, the wires are untwisted for a few centimeters and clamped into cylindrical sensor in a parallel orientation with a small gap between them.

[image: Image attached for clarity]

What physical principles is a device like this based on and how does it work?

Comment: Induction and/or capacitive coupling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAQBYs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The device uses capacitive coupling.

This information is missing on company site, but can be found in a [disputed patent](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/99/26/66/82e0307ce8d12d/US8548099.pdf) referenced from there.